# Cost compare for the today and yesterday same time data Mysq;

Tags: python, mysql

I have below table structure of MySQL table

```
timestamp  | agg_id | media_cost
1587121200 | 2      | 10
1587121200 | 3      | 5
1587121100 | 2      | 6
1587121200 | 2      | 2
1587341200 | 3      | 5
```

I have to run a query for every hour so that it will compare yesterday cost with today's cost for the time it runs and alerts if today cost is less than half of yesterday's cost and group by agg_id.

I'm using this below query as a reference, but not sure how to get the expected output

```
  select 
  today.datetime, 
  100 * (sum(today.cost) - sum(yesterday.cost))/sum(today.cost) as pctdiff, 
  sum(today.cost) as today, 
  sum(yesterday.cost) as yesterday 
  from (
  select datetime, cost, id 
  from table 
  where datetime between curdate() and now() - interval 1 hour
  ) as today 
  join (
  select datetime, cost, id 
  from table 
  where left(datetime,10) = curdate() - interval 1 day 
   ) as yesterday on today.id=yesterday.id 
  group by today.datetime 
  order by today.datetime asc ;
```

Can someone guide me here

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry you could have guided without full answer, as I'm zero experience in these queries stuff.I'm trying and I'm here for the guide, not for the answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Anyhow thanks

Comment: That IS the guide

Comment: @Strawberry Okay, will try